# Need SQL Update statement based off of select results in another query. Not sure how to combine the two

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My first select statement is this:

```
 Select AL.asset_key, AL.group_key, AL.entity_key
From assetlist As AL
Where Not Exists    (
                Select 1
                From assetgroup As AG
                Where AG.group_key = AL.group_key
                    And AG.entity_key = AL.entity_key
                )
```

The results of this query show me any asset that has been incorrectly assigned a group_key. We had a bug that was grabbing the first record based off of a non-unique field. So if I have two groups named 'Group 1' but the exist in different parent categories, the script that was writing the new records based of the first match for 'Group 1' and not checking to see if it is the group for that category. Anyway, its fixed, so I am trying to do a clean up script. The results of the query above gives me this:

```
 asset_key  group_key   entity_key
 352        25          3
 376        77          3
 378        77          3
```

Another query I have is to check the group_key versus the entity key to see what the correct value should be:

```
SELECT distinct
t1.Group_key, t1.entity_key, t1.group_id
FROM assetgroup t1 
INNER JOIN assetgroup t2 ON t2.Group_ID = t1.Group_ID 
WHERE t2.Group_key != t1.Group_key
and t2.entity_key != t1.entity_key
and t2.Group_ID = t1.Group_ID
order by t1.group_id
```

The result set looks like this:

```
Group_key   entity_key  group_id
25          1           CID
58          2           CID
59          3           CID
77          2           GROUP 1
79          3           GROUP 1
29          4           RENTAL
51          6           RENTAL
53          1           WAREHOUSE
36          5           WAREHOUSE
```

So looking at both result we see that group_key 25 does not belong to entity_key 3, so I need to update the asset. group_key to the correct group_key value of 59 as that is the correct value for entity 3 in group_id `CID`. The same goes for the other rows.

We have multiple customer databases that will all need this script run, so I can't do the easy thing and just look at these two and write some manual update. How can I script this to get it all done?

Here is a more detailed explanation of the data and what needs to be done:

- The assetgroup table links each asset to a group_id, fully determined by the group_key, which is unique in the table.
- Each assetgroup group_key is associated with an entity_key. Each entity_key is only in each group_id once.
- In the assets table, the group_key and the entity_key are listed, though the entity_key is supposed to be fully implied by the group_key.
- However, some asset rows have the wrong group_key, and need to be updated to the correct group_key of that entity in the same group_id as the wrong group_key.

Comment: How do you know that 59 entity 3 is associated with 25 e.1?

Comment: From the second query. The Assetgroup table keeps a record of each new group created and I confirmed that it is associated the entity it is created under correctly

Comment: Is there an automated way of confirming the association?

Comment: "group_key 25 does not belong to entity_key 1"? But your second query shows this. Did you mean that 25 does not belong to entity_key 3? I for one really need some help understanding the business meaning of the "group" and "identity" logical objects. Also, your answer to ron tornambe was useless... please show the actual steps "first we look here and see this exact value X, then we do that and change value Z to Y."

Comment: @David No one is huffy, except perhaps you. We are trying to help you! Frankly, if you don't understand your data, how do you expect anyone else to? We are asking you how the two sets of data relate to each other. From the given example data we don't understand the relationship between the parts and thus cannot guide you. That you had completely opposite wrong information in your post, and didn't take the time to answer ron tornambe in detail, left everyone guessing and wondering since it didn't make any sense! Please, please, take the time to give more detail so we can help you!

Comment: @ErikE you're absolutely correct. I apologize. I posted an answer I got from my co-worker if you would like to check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the query you're looking for.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.group_key = R.group_key
FROM
   Assets A
   INNER JOIN AssetGroup W -- Wrong
      ON A.group_key = W.group_key -- find group_id of wrong group_key
   INNER JOIN AssetGroup R -- Right
      ON A.entity_key = R.entity_key -- also W.entity_key = R.entity_key
      AND R.group_id = W.group_id -- wrong group_key still has right group_id
WHERE
   A.group_key <> R.group_key
```

Please note that your database tables are denormalized because the entity_key fully implies the group_key, but the group_key is repeated in the assets table. This is a database design anti-pattern that is against industry best practice. The group_key should not be in the assets table at all. At the very least, though not ideal, there should a constraint that prevents incorrect combinations of values from being entered, such as an FK relationship from the assets table to the assetgroup table on `(group_key, entity_key)`. This has its own problems such as making it impossible to move entities between groups. The group does not uniquely identify entities so it really is not part of the key and should be removed.

Ultimately, your group_keys are surrogates that replace each `(entity_key, group_id)` with a single value. But then you repeat the entity_key in the assets table. This makes no sense at all. If your name is `Joe Public`, and you get assigned a number uniquely referring to this full name, say, 28975, then why would you refer to yourself as `Joe 28975`? Either one, or the other. The problem with this is that you can say things like `Moe 28975` which doesn't refer to anyone at all! Then you have to look up person number 28975's REAL first name, and change `Moe` to `Joe`. This is not optimal.

In your case, the broken process looked up `Public` in the table based on only last name and pulled corresponding number 11645, giving `Joe 11645`, another invalid combination:

```
Last   First Number
------ ----- ------
Public Joe   29875
Public Moe   11645
```

So you had to go look up `11645`'s last name, and find the correct number for `Joe`. I hope this helps show how this scheme is mixed up.

I would also like to mildly object to the column order in your tables. In general, at least to me, it makes most sense to put parent columns before child columns. Putting child columns first is confusing (especially without explanation). And the suffix `id` is used almost universally in databases to mean internal identifiers. It is a little unsettling to see `group_id` and realize it is a text string instead of a number. In fact, this is another denormalization. What if you want to rename group_id `WAREHOUSE` to `WAREHOUSE 1` because you are adding a `WAREHOUSE 2`? Now you have to update the value in all the rows that reference it. Clearly, the group_ids are used by humans and have significance in and of themselves, so they should NOT be repeated over and over in many rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think that something like this would work (can't really check this myself).

I strongly recommend that you wrap this in a transaction before you try it out:

```
    with correctGroup(groupKey, entityKey) as (
        SELECT distinct t1.Group_key, t1.entity_key
        FROM assetgroup t1 INNER JOIN assetgroup t2 ON t2.Group_ID = t1.Group_ID 
        WHERE t2.Group_key != t1.Group_key
            and t2.entity_key != t1.entity_key
            and t2.Group_ID = t1.Group_ID)
    update  assetList
    from    assetList al join correctGroup cg on al.entity_key = cg.entitykey
    set     group_key = groupKey
    Where Not Exists (
                    Select 1
                    From assetgroup As AG
                    Where AG.group_key = AL.group_key
                        And AG.entity_key = AL.entity_key
                    )
```

Comment: it is giving me a syntax error near correctGroup and order(7th line).. I am not a sql guru, can you spot the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a co-worker of mine came up with the solution after laughing at my over-complicated efforts. Here is the query:

[image]

Sorry for not going into detail on the business logic behind this. At the time I did not think it pertinent but I see that it was now. Cheers all, thanks for the input and putting up with a huffy developer :)

Oh and my work firewall suddenly thinks I am trying a sql injection attack, thus the image and not the code.

Comment: I have to say that this style of query boggles the mind. It gets incredibly complicated incredibly fast, and in fact has 4 tables joined when there only need to be 3. It is almost impossible to traverse the logic of each join individually because of the nested subselects. Please show your coworker the query in my answer and suggest that using correct ANSI join syntax will help him/her write better queries. I promise you that my query is easier to understand, and performs better... so it wins on all counts.